# Variance of all unbiased estimators

Tags: regression, machine-learning, mathematical-statistics, classification

I study linear regression and I came into this True-False question of exam.

[image]

Answer of this question is False.

> I think based on Gauss–Markov theorem it must be true. Anyone can help
> me why it marked as a false sentence?